# JOOQ - Join on condition or not exit

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have the following query:

```
Map<BusinessRecord, List<BusinessAddressRecord>> resultMap = dslContext
        .select()
        .from(BUSINESS.leftJoin(BUSINESS_ADDRESS).on(BUSINESS.ID.eq(BUSINESS_ADDRESS.BUSINESS_ID)))
        .where(BUSINESS.IDENTIFIER.equal(identifier))
        .and(BUSINESS_ADDRESS.DEACTIVATED_AT.isNull())
        .fetchGroups(
                b -> b.into(BUSINESS),
                a -> a.into(BUSINESS_ADDRESS)
        );
```

Unfortunately this returns null if a business has no address listed, I managed to resolve this by doing:

```
  Map<BusinessRecord, List<BusinessAddressRecord>> resultMap = dslContext
          .select()
          .from(BUSINESS.leftJoin(BUSINESS_ADDRESS).on(
                  BUSINESS.ID.eq(BUSINESS_ADDRESS.BUSINESS_ID).and(BUSINESS_ADDRESS.DEACTIVATED_AT.equals(null))
          ))
          .where(BUSINESS.IDENTIFIER.equal(identifier))
          .fetchGroups(
                  b -> b.into(BUSINESS),
                  a -> a.into(BUSINESS_ADDRESS)
          );
```

But this is saying the 'and' in

```
and(BUSINESS_ADDRESS.DEACTIVATED_AT.equals(null))
```

is deprecated, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

#### About the deprecated API

> But this is saying the 'and' in [...] is deprecated

See the [deprecation notice on that method](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Condition.html#and(java.lang.Boolean))? It says:

> **Deprecated.** - 3.8.0 - [[#4763]](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4763) - Use [`and(Condition)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Condition.html#and(org.jooq.Condition)) (typically with [`DSL.trueCondition()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#trueCondition()), [`DSL.falseCondition()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#falseCondition()), or [`DSL.noCondition()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#noCondition()) as the parameter) or [`and(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Condition.html#and(org.jooq.Field)) instead. Due to ambiguity between calling this method using [`Field.equals(Object)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) argument, vs. calling the other method via a [`Field.equal(Object)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#equal(T)) argument, this method will be removed in the future.

You're using `Object.equals()`, not jOOQ's `Field.equal()` (or `Field.eq()`). There's an `and(Boolean)` overload, which has been causing the kind of trouble you ran into many times, which is why it's deprecated, and will be removed in jOOQ 3.15.0 with [#11242](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11242). After that, your code using `equals()` instead of `equal()` simply won't compile anymore.

#### Nulls

In SQL (and by consequence in jOOQ), you cannot compare values with `NULL` using ordinary comparison operators, because the result of such a comparison is always `NULL` (not `TRUE` or `FALSE`). SQL implements [three valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).

Replace your predicate by:

```java
and(BUSINESS_ADDRESS.DEACTIVATERD_AT.isNull())
```